# Angular 4 *ngFor loop parse value to directive as parameter

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have the following *ngFor loop and inside the loop I've got another div where I have applied a directive which expects an object parameter :

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div [directiveName]="{testParamKey: item.name}"></div>
</div>
```

It gives me an error : "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".
I wonder how do i pass this parameter using the item from the for loop ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a null item in your array. You can do `item?.name` in the template, which will only read name if `item` is not null. It's called the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

Comment: How do you call it in the directive?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.. When I replace the line where [directiveName] is with {{item?.name}} it does print out the values but it doesn't parse it to the directive for some reason..

Comment: In the directive name I've got @Input('directiveName') data: any; and i get the parsed data which should be data.testParamKey;

Comment: this works perfectly, i had a typo in the original code.... thanks for your time guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the optional operator. `?`

```
<div [directiveName]="{testParamKey: item?.name}"></div>
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for me.. :( If i want to print out the item.name as {{item.name}} without any parsing it does print the name.. but when trying to parse it as param it doesn't work with the optional operator.